# TypeError: item.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using react and redux and I'm trying a simple example.
If I clicked the button, then the number should increment by 1. 
But when I currently click the button you'll see the following error, `TypeError: item.map is not a function`. Is there a problem with my code?

```
class Menu extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }

  plus = () =>{
    this.props.getplus();
  }

  render() {
    const {item } = this.props.item
    return (
      <div>
        {item.map(items => {
          <buttom onClick={this.plus}> + </button>  <div>{count}</div>     
        }               
      </div>
    )
   }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   item: state.item
 })

export default connect(mapStateToProps , { getItems, getplus }) (Menu);
```

itemAction.js

```
export const getItems = () =>{
  return {
    type: GET_ITEMS
  }
}

export const getplus = () => {
  return {
    type: PLUS_ITEMS
  }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  item: [
    {
      count:0
    },
  ],
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state
      }
      default:
        return state;
   case PLUS_ITEMS:
     return {
       item: state.item.count++
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: map iterates on array, not numbers

Comment: `state.item.count++` mutates the state which is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

```
case PLUS_ITEMS:
 return {
   item: state.item.count++
 }
}
```

There is no `state.item.count` in your state. `state.item` is an array. Fix this and see if that takes care of that error.

Comment: so i tried {item.map(({count}) => ( <div onClick={this.Plus}> + </div> <div>{count} </div> ))}    is not object map ??...

Answer (score 0):

You need a default case for the reducer.

```
case GET_ITEMS:
    return{
        ...state
    }
case PLUS_ITEMS:
     return{
item:state.item.count++
     }
default:
        return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

state.item[0].count++ should work, if there is just one object in your items array.

Comment: As Anthony K said below, state.item is an array, whose first element is count

Answer (score 0):

Reducer.js

make item as object instead of array and spread state.

```
const initialState = {
  item:{
      count:0
    },
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state
      }
      default:
        return state;
   case PLUS_ITEMS:
     return {
       ...state,
       item: state.item.count++
     }
   }
 }
```